# Letters change when saving tab into shp in QGIS

Tags: qgis, shapefile, mapinfo, encoding, tab

I am working in QGIS 2.18. When I open and then save a .tab file as .shp file I get different symbols in the letters of the attribute table. I don't know what coding option I should use in order to see the original letters (Spanish alphabet symbols: ñ, accents, etc...).

[image]

By default the "save vector layer as..." dialog window chooses UTF-8.

[image]

I already tried some other options but I get unreadable text, so I rather ask before I do something that hurts the file.

In fact, when I open the .tab file in MapInfo I can see it correctly. Is it something related to the system settings of the program (QGIS/MapInfo)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [ISO 8859-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1) encoding to read Spanish text correctly (along with various other countries).

Comment: I did as you suggest it but I get question marks "?" now instead of question marks over a black diamond.

Comment: @Pescariz - I cannot replicate your issue. I have a .tab file containing similar text with accents etc and I used the `ISO 8859-1` encoding when using the `Save As...` option. Output shapefile produces the correct result. Could you upload your .tab files to a public server so that others could test it?

Comment: It must have been because I had the file opened in MapInfo while working in QGIS. Closed both programs, started QGIS, and did all the procedure again and now it works perfect. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Pescariz - That makes sense, glad you got it working ;)